# SUM days to the DB date

Tags: java

When I try to add 30 days with the date obtained in the Database is giving this error.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

String reportDate = df.format(today);


String endDay = rset.getString("vip_end");

endDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30)
```

Error

```
Error:(76, 70) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method add(int,int)
  location: variable endDay of type java.lang.String
```

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag?

Comment: Your first 3 lines of code have nothing to do with your last 2 lines. Please take more care in authoring your posts.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate                        // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.now(                            // Capture the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )    // Specify your time zone. Use proper `Continent/Region` names, never 2-4 character pseudo-zones such as IST or PST or EST or CST.
)                                // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.plusDays( 30 )                  // Add days to determine a later date. Returns a new `LocalDate` object rather than mutating the original.
.toString()                      // Generate text representing the value of this `LocalDate` object, in standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD.
```

> 2019-06-30

## No `add` method on `String`

You declared `endDay` to be a `String`. Then you called the method `add`. But there is no method `add` on `String` class. Thus your error, as explained in the error message.

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Stop doing that.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

### Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. **For any given moment, the date varies** around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

### Generating text

Your output format is in standard ISO 8601 format. This format is used by default in the `LocalDate` class for parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = LocalDate.of( 2019 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ).toString() ;
```

> 2019-01-23

### Date math

Add 30 days.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;
LocalDate later = today.plusDays( 30 ) ;
```

The *java.time* classes follow the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern. So they return a new fresh object based on the values of the original.